# Give Priority to Specified Column Values of Joined Table - Show main property image

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need some help with this MySQL statement. In my real estate app, I have a "properties" table and a "propertyImages" table. In the propertyImages table, there is a column that identifies which image the user selected as the "main" image, simply "yes" or "no" (I can change this from "yes"/"no" to "1"/"0" if necessary). The main image is as it sounds - the photo the user wants to showcase for this property. Sometimes users select a main property image and sometimes they don't. In fact, sometimes they don't upload images at all.

Here's my example:

Table 1: properties

```
id   |  status   | all other columns
------------------------  
1    | published | blah
2    | published | blah
3    | published | blah
4    | published | blah
```

Table 2: propertyImages

```
id  | propID |    imgSrc    | primaryImg
----------------------------------
52  | 2      | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
53  | 2      | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
54  | 2      | imgs/xxx.jpg | yes
55  | 3      | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
56  | 3      | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
57  | 3      | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
58  | 4      | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
```

Notice how property 1 has **0 images**, property 2 **has** a primary image ("yes") and property 3 and 4 do **not have** a primary image (all rows are "no").

How can I create a SELECT statement that Joins both tables and returns one row per property (with the primary image in the row...or another image if there is no primary image, or NULL if there are no images at all). The priority of the image row selected goes...

1. If property has a main image, show that.
2. If property has no primary image show any other image for this property
3. If property has no images at all...show "null"

I want this to be the output after the tables are joined:

```
id  |   *   | imgSrc       | primaryImg
----------------------------------
1   | blah  | NULL         | NULL
2   | blah  | imgs/xxx.jpg | yes
3   | blah  | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
4   | blah  | imgs/xxx.jpg | no
```

In the mySQL statement I also need to include a couple of conditions. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM properties 
LEFT JOIN propertyImages 
ON properties.id = propertyImages.propertyID
WHERE properties.status = "published"
AND propertyImages.deleted = "no" -- Comment: not shown in table above
GROUP BY properties.id
```

I don't know if a "Left Join" is what I should be using. I also use "Group By" to prevent duplicates (I want unique property rows, not one row per image), although I'm not sure if "Group By" is the most efficient way to do this. I've test this in a million different ways and I'm not getting the results that I need. Also, what is the terminology that I should use to explain/search for this? Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Use `max(primaryImg)`.`'y'` is larger than `'n'`, and it will be `NULL` if there are not any matching records.Then combine it with `LIMIT 1` in your correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a couple of subqueries ... this one chooses the id of the most-recently uploaded image for each property. (That's the image with the largest `id` value.) It gives back either one row or no rows for each value of `propID`. That means you can `LEFT JOIN` to it without changing the number of rows in your result set.

```
                   SELECT MAX(id) id, propID 
                     FROM propertyImage
                    WHERE deleted = 'no'
                    GROUP BY propID
```

This one choose the id of the most-recently-uploaded primary image. Yes, you have only one primary image, but that's OK.  Your database doesn't know there's only one primary image, so if there happen to be more you need to select just one.

```
                   SELECT MAX(id) id, propID 
                     FROM propertyImage
                    WHERE deleted = 'no'
                      AND primaryImage = 'yes'
                    GROUP BY propID
```

Next, left join those two subqueries to your detail tables. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Ra9UfxPTcYQAdSK2ETMPw/0)

```
   SELECT something or other 
     FROM properties p
     LEFT JOIN (
                   SELECT MAX(id) id, propID 
                     FROM propertyImage
                    WHERE deleted = 'no'
                      AND primaryImage = 'yes'
                    GROUP BY propID
          ) primary ON p.propID = pri.propID
     LEFT JOIN (
                   SELECT MAX(id) id, propID 
                     FROM propertyImage
                    WHERE deleted = 'no'
                    GROUP BY propID
          ) other ON p.propID = other.propID
      LEFT JOIN propertyImage i ON i.id = COALESCE(primary.id, other.id)
```

The trick here is the `COALESCE()` function in the ON clause of the last. It uses its first argument if that isn't null, or the second argument if that isn't null, or null. So,  `COALESCE(primary.id, other.id)` gets the id of the image you want .. primary if it exists, otherwise some other image, or null.

Finally, make your `SELECT` clause yield the columns you want.

```
  SELECT p.id, p.this, p.that, p.something, i.imgSrc, i.primaryImage
```

Comment: @Gordon's answer is excellent, but relies on window functions only available in MySQL 8 or later.

Comment: Thank you! This works wonderfully. Gordons answer works too, however, I'm selecting yours as the final answer because you explained everything well, you provided a working fiddle and you've made it easy for me to utilize this code for other things in the future. I like that Gordons answer is compact and easy to implement, but your explanation helps me understand things better. Thank you so much. It's such a relief to have this resolved! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `row_number()` for the prioritization:

```
SELECT p.*, pi.*
FROM properties p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pi.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyID ORDER BY primaryImg DESC) as seqnum
      FROM propertyImages pi
      WHERE pi.deleted = 'no'
     ) pi
     ON p.id = pi.propertyID AND seqnum = 1
WHERE p.status = "published"
```